# Move label on top on select other options select with css

Tags: css, sass

How can I move (or make appear) a label on top of a select with css by choosing other options than the first. The first one is actually the content of the label, e.g "Select options". I am working with ruby on rails so I just can use css for make that possible.

Here is the code what I tried, but it does not work:

```
select option:checked:not(:first-child) ~ .label-select
```

And the html is something like this (generated by rails):

```
<select>
   <option>Select options ...</option>
   <option>Option 1</option>
   <option>Option 2</option>
   <option>Option 3</option>
<label class="label-select">Select options ...<label>
```

Comment: What is the parent? You can turn the parent to flexbox and then use the order property for the label or select. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items

Comment: Sorry but that is not about the position of the label. It is about to change label style by selecting other options than the first one at select